Does "popular tags” need to be repeated in the “How to tag?” suggestions when editing a question?
My question is shown in the title. If someone does not understand my question, you can see it in the picture below:

There are two things that can be seen from the picture:

"favor using existing popular tags"
"popular tags"

Why do we need to repeat the same dialogue twice?
Am I missing something?
Should we delete one (preferably #2. "popular tags") for being redundant?

Clearly the tags are really popular. Anyway, which one do you suggest we remove?

@Mast I have edited the post.

It's probably just an oversight. Maybe someone added one of the popular tags links without noticing that one already exists.

@CaveJohnson Actually who is “someone”, the developers of these sites?

@user1176409 Possibly or it could be content that is easily editable by anyone so it could be an employee that has that ability.
